# Getting an erro/warning while integrating camera

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Why do i get this error/warning

```
[INFO] Error in success callback: Camera1 = TypeError: Result of expression 'image1' [undefined] is not an object.
```

**note: I get this error/warning after i take a photo from the camera when i click the `Use` button**

My code is as follows; i have directly copied it from the PhoneGap documentation. But why does this error still exist ?

```
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
                                       destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
                                       }); 

           function onSuccess(imageData) {
           var image1 = Ext.getCmp('myImageId');
           image1.setSrc("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
           }

           function onFail(message) {
           alert('Failed because: ' + message);
           }
```

**Code**

This is called Image.js and its a View. I also need to display the image on the screen too

```
Ext.define('app.view.Image',{

           extend:'Ext.Panel',

           xtype:'myImageId',

           id:'myImageId',

           config: {



           title:'Image',

           fullscreen: true,

           scrollable: false,



           }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Result of expression 'image1' [undefined] is not an object.

It states that your "`image1`" is not an object. i.e whatever you have in that variable is not an object. It's value is `undefined`.

Just make sure you are getting the reference to the appropriate `image` component in your `SenchaTouch` code and then giving it's reference to `image1`

Comment: How should i do this ? `Ext.getCmp('myImageId')` will be getting the image and setting it to image1 right ? Help

Comment: Well yes, and i copied the code from the phonegap website http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: Could you tell me what should be in the `myImageId` component. I am really stuck here :(

Comment: Can you please post your entire image component sencha touch code?

Comment: I have updated my question. I too need to display the image as well